# Confusion in request count via Artillery

Tags: artillery

I was trying artillery and ran the load test for approx 90mins on an endpoint in AWS. What I have observed the request count in ALB is near about 5K. However, the Artillery test results shows 456000 as http.requests. May be I am not understanding this, but why the request count in ALB is way less than in the below summary report (i.e. 456000 http.requests).

Artillery Summary

```
errors.ETIMEDOUT: .............................................................. 429019
http.codes.200: ................................................................ 27068
http.codes.401: ................................................................ 13
http.request_rate: ............................................................. 86/sec
http.requests: ................................................................. 456000
http.response_time:
  min: ......................................................................... 99
  max: ......................................................................... 20877
  median: ...................................................................... 20136.3
  p95: ......................................................................... 20136.3
  p99: ......................................................................... 20543.1
http.responses: ................................................................ 27081
vusers.completed: .............................................................. 26981
vusers.created: ................................................................ 456000
vusers.created_by_name.Test API: ........................................ 456000
vusers.failed: ................................................................. 429019
vusers.session_length:
  min: ......................................................................... 325.9
  max: ......................................................................... 25000.9
  median: ...................................................................... 20136.3
  p95: ......................................................................... 23162.4
  p99: ......................................................................... 24594.7
```

Here is my Artillery script

```
config:
  target: "https://<some-endpoint-in-aws-behind-alb>"
  http:
    timeout: 25
  phases:
    - duration: 1200
      arrivalRate: 10
      name: Warm up
      
    - duration: 1200
      arrivalRate: 50
      rampTo: 250
      name: Ramp up load 1
      
    - duration: 1200
      arrivalRate: 50
      rampTo: 300
      name: Ramp up load 2
      
    - duration: 1800
      arrivalRate: 30
      name: Sustained load
```